# How do I reference my UICollectionview from my ViewController from a different class?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I want to automatically scroll to a specific place in my UICollectionView using the method `scrollToItem` however I want to do this outside of my UIViewController where my UICollectionView lives how do I reference it in my other class?

````
import SideMenu
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var menu: SideMenuNavigationController?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imgArr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: MenuListController())
        menu?.leftSide = true
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = menu
        SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.view)
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapMenu(){
        present(menu!, animated: true)
    }

}


extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCollectionViewCell
        cell?.img.image = UIImage(named:imgArr[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
    
}

class MenuListController:UITableViewController{
    
    var items = ["First", "Second"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellmenu")
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmenu", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("selected " + items[indexPath.row])
        // WHAT DO I DO HERE????
       
       
        
    }
    
}```
````

Comment: Make a delegate call.

Answer (score 1):

Making a delegate will only suitable if your view controllers are top of each other in navigation stack. If it is not top of each other use Notification Center instead. Moreover, you can pass `[String:Any]` dictionary in `object` argument.

In Main view controller (Having Collection view), create an observer(in viewdidload and Assign a selector).

```
let notificationCenter = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter.addObserver(self,
                               selector: #selector(didTapOnTableView()),
                               name: Notification.Name(
   rawValue: "didTapOnTableView"),
                               object: nil)

@objc func didTapOnTableView(){
    // Do your code
}
```

Post notification from second view controller (is didselect of tableview)

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("didTapOnTableView"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make delegate or closure to get call back on first controller. Following example is using closure var rowSelected:((Int)->())?

````
import SideMenu
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var menu: SideMenuNavigationController?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imgArr = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"]
    
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let rootVC = MenuListController()
        rootVC.rowSelected = {[weak self] index in
            //Perform action here
            print(index)
        }
        menu = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: MenuListController())
        menu?.leftSide = true
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = menu
        SideMenuManager.default.addPanGestureToPresent(toView: self.view)
    }
    
    @IBAction func didTapMenu(){
        present(menu!, animated: true)
    }

}


extension ViewController : UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imgArr.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? DataCollectionViewCell
        cell?.img.image = UIImage(named:imgArr[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
    }
    
}

class MenuListController:UITableViewController{
    
    var items = ["First", "Second"]
    var rowSelected:((Int)->())?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UITableView.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cellmenu")
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmenu", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
      override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("selected " + items[indexPath.row])
        // WHAT DO I DO HERE????
       rowSelected?(items[indexPath.row])
       
        
    }
    
}```
````